# Kivy 1.10 UIX with multiple custom widgets on screen

Tags: python-2.7, opengl, 3d, kivy

I'm new to Kivy so still learning how to make content with the library. My question is related to the widgets and layouts. I'm trying to create some kind of 3D visualizer with OpenGL and just started looking at the built-in examples 3DRendering you can check it [here](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/bem3qpcctlzlmxp/AAB2U3TXJvY7vGLlno6-sfOla?dl=0).

I've changed the Original Example and in the class Renderer(Widget) i've added a method for reposition the widget itself:

```
def reposition_b1(self, *args):
    self.pos = self.x, self.height / 2 - self.height / 2
```

and in the RendererApp Class within the build method:

```
def build(self):
    b = BoxLayout(orientation='horizontal')
    r1= Renderer()
    r1.reposition_b1(500)
    r2= Renderer()
    b.add_widget(r1)
    b.add_widget(r2)
    return b
```

So from what I understand about Kivy it should give the next result (The magenta color in the background is just a reference):[expected result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eTO9t.png)

But instead I just got a single 3D model in the visualizer. Any Hints about what I'm missing?

Comment: I don't think the 3d rendering shader respects the widget position, so both would draw in the same place. This is something you'll need to add to the code for it to work as you expect. You can check if this is the problem by e.g. drawing two different 3D objects and seeing if they are on top of one another.

Comment: Also, your attempt to set self.pos won't do anything as the BoxLayout places its children according to its layout rules.

Comment: @inclement do you think if i create them as a Layout instead of widget could it work?. Also i've tried to place two different 3d models and both show.